# Windows 1903 Update to 20H2

Tags: windows-10, updates

I received an old notebook, already used, which I will donate to a school for needy children.

His system is Windows 1903 OS build 18362.900
Notebook Model:
`HP Pavilion 11 x360 PC`
4Gb of ram memory
System drive with 46Gb of free space

When I ran windows update, an update for Windows 20H2 appeared, but after 100% installed, before finishing it showed the error 0xc1900101.

I'm trying to update step by step, through Windows Catalog, but without success.

Before installing the downloaded KB's, I ran the troubleshooter in Windows update and everything went smoothly.

First I try to update the 1903 version itself with its cumulative updates that were not installed by the previous owner of the Notebook.

Update via Windows Catalog:
The only KB's I was able to install were the servicing-stack:
`KB4520390 and KB4598479`

The KB's below, reach 100% in the installation and then, before finishing, they show the message Failed:
`KB4517389, KB4594443 and KB4592449`

Note:
I was able to check in the log, that `KB4592449` canceled with error
`0x80073701` and KB's `KB4517389 and KB4594443` I couldn't see what the cancellation code was, but it must have been the same.

Then I tried to download the KB that updates to version 1909, but it was not found in the Windows Catalog:
`KB4517245`

Can this version of Windows 1903 no longer be updated because of expiring support?

SetupDiag logs:

ERROR lines of Report Setupact:

```
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error                 SYSPRP SPPNP: Failed to enumerate primitive driver packages. Err = 0x13[gle=0x00000013]
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error                 SYSPRP SPPNP: Unable to install primitive drivers. Err = 0x13[gle=0x00000013]
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::DeleteValue: Error from RegOpenKeyExW on key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep\OfflineState\Specialize; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Win32 error (19), could not execute actions
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Error      [0x0f0435] SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: An error occurred while either deciding if we need to specialize or while specializing; dwRet = 0x13[gle=0x00000013]
2022-06-15 03:14:53, Info       [0x0640ae] IBSLIB PublishMessage: Publishing message [Windows Setup was unable to configure Windows to run on computer hardware.]
```

Report SetupDiagResults:

```
Matching Profile found: FindRollbackFailure - 3A43C9B5-05B3-4F7C-A955-88F991BB5A48
SetupDiag version: 1.6.2107.27002
System Information:
    Machine Name = NOTEBOOK
    Manufacturer = Hewlett-Packard
    Model = HP Pavilion 11 x360 PC
    HostOSArchitecture = 1046
    FirmwareType = PCAT
    BiosReleaseDate = 20140509000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = Default System BIOS
    BiosVersion = F.08
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.18362
    HostOSBuildString = 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.1766 (vb_release_svc_prod1.220607-1938)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = 
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 14/06/2022 23:14:30
    UpgradeEndTime = 15/06/2022 03:14:53
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 04:00:23
    CV = 9TJyo1GMl0ubuPwC
    ReportId = 2F285C59-E8B3-49C3-BC83-BED2F4498B75


Error: SetupDiag reports rollback failure found.
Last Phase = Pre SysPrep
Last Operation = Upgrade security
Error = 0xC1900101-0x30018
LogEntry: 

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137162/discussion-on-question-by-clamarc-windows-1903-update-to-20h2).

Answer (score 0):

For my specific case, this worked:

1. Download the Installation Tool for the 21H1 version of Windows 10 and create an installation flash drive.
2. Change in the BIOS so that the Pendrive is loaded at Boot.
3. After the update, the System was Installed as Windows 10 Home.
4. In the Computer properties, verify that the Product ID is in Digital License AAAOEM or OEM.
5. On the Windows Update screen, there is a link `Update to Pro Version`, where you are asked for a key for the update to be started. Just enter the generic Windows key for the process to start.

See the link:
[going pro how to upgrade windows 10 home](https://www.zdnet.com/article/going-pro-how-to-upgrade-windows-10-home-without-hassles/)

Generic Key:
`VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T`

The System may issue a `Update could not be performed at this time, please try later...` message. In this case, just continue using your Computer normally and the System itself will take care of updating at the right time.

After the above procedures, the System has been updated to Windows Pro version 21H1.

`Note`:
This generic product key will only work if your hardware has already been purchased a Pro license.